# Percentage of Total within Category in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am looking to create a comparison of how percentage of totals change over time, which will illustrate how the win-loss ratio changes. I am hoping to create the following chart based on data set up in the following way.

Currently, I have CNT(Game) in the Rows with the Date and W/L fields in Columns. W/L is also listed as the color.  Whenever I convert the CNT(Game) to Percentage of Total, it gives me the overall total and not within that month.. I changed the level to Month but that did not help

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Compute Using [W/L]. That should fix it. There shouldn't be any need to have "At the level" involved - unless it's slightly more complex than your question suggests of course, which is often the case.